# Can I delete the folders of the older version of R?

Tags: r, version

In the R folder, I have 3 subfolders whose name is 3 different versions of R: R-3.5.3, R-3.6.2, R-4.0.5.
Why does R keep this previous version of R? Can I uninstall the two older versions (R-3.5.3, R-3.6.2)? If yes, should I rather simply delete these folders or should I use uninstall.exe? I am afraid that if using the uninstall.exe will delete all versions of R. The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: What is your OS

Comment: The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: No this doesn't answer my questions. I don't want to uninstall R, but only know with the folder from the previous versions of R are still used or whether they can be deleted.

Comment: You can use `.libPaths` to get all the paths